# How to use in python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I would like to use a numeric variable regular expression part.

What should I do if I want to use a variable in this part `(?P<hh>\d)`

I want to output lines that contain the input number.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?  What variable would you like to use, and what would be your expected input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [string interpolation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
m = re.compile(r'\d{%d}:\d{%d}' % (var1, var2))
```

If the vars aren't already integers you may need to convert types like so:

```
m = re.compile(r'\d{%d}:\d{%d}' % (int(var1), int(var2)))
```

Comment: Would that be `'\d{%i}:\d{%i}'` for the integer value (even though `%d` works)?

Comment: Doesn't matter, `%i` and `%d` are exactly the same.  I've always used and seen `%d`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to put a variable in place of (?P<hh>\d)       sys.argv[1]:sys.argv[2] to find and correct the output line going to

Comment: @ParkKwansik Without changing your code too much... `LOG_FILE = '/home/text'
hh = sys.argv[1]
m = '%s:%s' % (hh, sys.argv[2])
f = open(LOG_FILE)
lines = f.readlines(10000)

for line in lines:
  r1 = line.find(m)
  if r1:
    print line

f.close()` I'm assuming you want to take sys.argv[1] and sys.argv[2] and turn them into a string separated by : then search for lines with that string and print them.  There's no reason in that case to use a regular expression, so I switched to using the find string function.  I removed some unnecessary code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear.

If you want to capture **some specific part of the regex**, you have to create groups (using pharentesis):

```
hh = sys.argv[1]
m = re.compile(r'(?P<hh>\d):(\d{2})')
match = m.match(hh)

print match.group(1)
print match.group(2)
```

for example, if `hh = '1:23'`, the above code will print:

> 1
>   23

---

Now, if what you need is **replace `\d{2}` by some variable**, you can do:

```
variable = r'\d{2}'
m = re.compile(r'(?P<hh>\d):%s' % variable)
```

or **if you just want to replace the `2`**, you can do:

```
variable = '2'
m = re.compile(r'(?P<hh>\d):\d{%s}' % variable)
```

---

Another option could be using:

```
r'(?P<hh>\d):{0}'.format(variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in as a string (I'd escape it first):

```
m = re.compile(re.escape(hh) + r':\d{2}')
```